# Prove $Img (\psi)= G/H \times G/K$,G is a group, $H \unlhd G$, $K \unlhd G$ and $HK=G$ Let $\psi (g)=\psi(gH,gK)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G is  a group, $H \unlhd G$, $K \unlhd G$  and $HK=G$

Let $\psi (g)=(gH,gK)$

Prove $Img (\psi)= G/H \times G/K$

---

Img $(\psi) =\{  (gH,gK) :g\in G \}$ for the same $g \in G$

$G/H \times G/K = \{ (g_1H,g_2K), \forall g_1,g_2 \in G \}$

**showing** ( $Img (\psi) \subset G/H \times G/K$ )

trivial just set $g_1 =g_2$

**showing** ($ G/H \times G/K \subset Img (\psi) $)

Let $(xH,yH)$ be an arbitrary element of $G/H \times G/K$ from $G=HK$ we can let $x=hk$ and $y=h'k'$

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
(xH,yK) & = (hkH,h'k'K)
         \\& = (hkHh',h'k'Kk)
       \\ & = (h'Hhk,h'kKk')
         \\ & = (h'Hk,h'kK)
          \\ & =(h'k H,h'kK)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Anything wrong, especially for  $ G/H \times G/K \subset Img (\psi) $?.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair it's a bit confusing what you are doing in the last part and definitely one needs some time to parse it all. The proof seems to be true, but I would recommend writing it in a clearer fashion. Here's how you can do it.

We'll use the elementary fact that $hH = h'H = H$ and $kK = k'K = K$. Then we have:

$$(hkH,h'k'K) = (hHk, h'K) = (h'Hk,h'kK) = (h'kH,h'kK) = \psi(h'k)$$